# Override DbSet.Remove() or Restore Entity values within DbContext ChangeTracker.DetectChanges()

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext

The current issue that I am facing is that I am implementing a Soft Delete on all objects, but `.Remove()` on an Entity will remove foreign keys during it's process.

MyObject (ie):

> Id = 1
>
> Name = Blah
>
> PageID = null (was 10 before .Remove() was called, I want to preserve this during SoftDelete)

Is is possible to override `public virtual TEntity Remove(TEntity entity)`? or modify my `ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();` section?

Like I briefly mentioned, I am using `ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();` to set the Entity (`ObjectStateEntry`) back to Modified (`entry.ChangeState(EntityState.Modified);`) and setting another Property `IsActive` to false, however the "stripping" of other fields has already been done when .Remove() was called.

MVC creates Controllers for all my objects and within the `DeleteConfirm` is `db.entityObject.Remove(entity)`.

... or is there a different approach I should be looking into?

I can provide more details, please let me know what you may need.

Example within a Controller:

```
// POST: MyObject/Delete/5
[HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(Guid id)
{
    MyObject myObject = db.MyObject.Find(id);
    db.MyObject.Remove(myObject);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Subset of my `DbContext` code:

```
public class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
        
        objectContext.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(
            EntityState.Added | 
            EntityState.Modified | 
            EntityState.Deleted);

        foreach (ObjectStateEntry entry in objectStateEntryList)
        {
            if (!entry.IsRelationship)
            {
                switch (entry.State)
                {
                    case EntityState.Deleted:
                        entry.ChangeState(EntityState.Modified);
                        ((BaseObject)entry.Entity).IsActive = false;
                        

                        //Update #1
                        this.Entry(entry.Entity).Reload();
                        
                        
                        //Is is possible to "restore" the original object?
                        //or override .Remove()?
                        
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        
        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

## Update 1:

Is it as simple as calling the following?

```
this.Entry(entry.Entity).Reload();
```

I think this worked, I understand this might be another database call, but resolves for now.  Further testing needed.

Comment: Why not just update the `IsActive` property? I know this soft-delete approach is often advocated, [even by the EF team themselves](https://github.com/rowanmiller/Demo-TechEd2014), but I always think: why not just update if in the end it *is* an update? One other reason is that cascaded *hard* delete is fundamentally different than its *soft* counterpart.

Comment: I'd like to continue to use the `context.MyObject.Remove(myObject)` that the scaffolding creates.  Plus, while I didn't mentioned it, after `ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();` I have implemented my own Audit Log for the Object and all Properties, sending a "SoftDelete" to the Audit Log keeps everything together.

Comment: More than a day looking for a little of light and finally here a ray of hope... thanks for the "Update 1" @Derek.

Answer (score 1):

Let me suggest to @Derek the:

## Update 2:

```cs
public class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
        
        objectContext.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(
            EntityState.Added | 
            EntityState.Modified | 
            EntityState.Deleted);

        foreach (ObjectStateEntry entry in objectStateEntryList)
        {
            if (!entry.IsRelationship)
            {
                switch (entry.State)
                {
                    case EntityState.Deleted:
                        // Update #2
                        // ---------
                        // Set the state to 'Unchanged'.
                        // Only updated fields will be sent to the Db.
                        entry.ChangeState(EntityState.Unchanged);
                        ((BaseObject)entry.Entity).IsActive = false;
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        
        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Thanks to [Entity Framework Core: Soft Delete](https://www.ryansouthgate.com/2019/01/07/entity-framework-core-soft-delete/) blog post from Ryan Southgate.

Comment: // Set the state to 'Unchanged'.
This comment was very helpful for me. In my case, I changed the state to 'modified' instead of 'unchanged' and then it wouldn't work.